# Python Geopandas failing to read, misread 750MB zip ESRI gdb file but not 200MB zip ESRI gdb file

Tags: python-3.x, geospatial, geopandas, esri

I am trying to read ESRI gdb zip file into geopandas [here](https://hakku.gtk.fi/en/locations/search?location_id=3) (about 200MB, success) and [here](https://hakku.gtk.fi/en/locations/search?location_id=1) (about 750MB, failure). The failure means that there are many meta missing fields, as described in lyr -metafiles, and many rows missing in the final result. I read the files in the following way:

```
import geopandas as gd
df3 = gd.read_file('maapera_20_50k_etrs_tm35fin_gdb.zip')
df3.head()
```

**How can I read large geospatial files into Python and how to resolve the issue with geopandas?**

Comment: No idea about solution to this but you may try R alternative first to see whether the files are corrupted or not, found something [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/118106).

Comment: This seems to be a bug in geopandas, tested with smaller data set so the solution may be to find a tool to slice the gdb.zip file and then read with geopandas.